# Update remembered value using arguments

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

I have a Composable in which a remembered value (an offset) needs to be updated both by the Composable itself and also from the calling side (using the Composable's arguments) -- how can I achieve this?

In particular, I have the following piece of code. The value I'm talking about is the `offset` in `NavigableBox`: I need to both be able to control it by dragging the box and by setting it manually using the value from `OffsetInputField` which is passed as an argument.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            Surface {
                Box {
                    var boxOffset by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero) }

                    NavigableBox(boxOffset)
                    OffsetInputField { offset ->
                        offset.toFloat().let { boxOffset = Offset(it, it) }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun OffsetInputField(onInput: (String) -> Unit) {
    var value by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    TextField(
        value = value,
        onValueChange = { value = it },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Go),
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onGo = { onInput(value) })
    )
}

@Composable
fun NavigableBox(initOffset: Offset) {
    var offset by remember(initOffset) { mutableStateOf(initOffset) }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .pointerInput(Unit) { detectTransformGestures { _, pan, _, _ -> offset += pan } }
    ) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .size(100.dp)
            .offset { IntOffset(offset.x.roundToInt(), offset.y.roundToInt()) }
            .background(Color.Blue)
        )
    }
}
```

In the current implementation the dragging works fine until a new value is passed as `OffsetInputField`'s input -- then the box stops responding to dragging. I assume it is because the `MutableState` object containing the offset changes when gets recalculated and the box doesn't observe it anymore.

I already tried using unidirectional data flow in `NavigableBox` (passing `offset` value and `onOffsetChange` lambda to it, but then dragging doesn't work as expected: the box just jiggles around its initial position, returning back to it when the gesture stops.

*In case anyone interested, I'm developing an app where the draggable box is a map, and the text field is used for searching objects on it: the map is moved to be centered on an object entered.*

Comment: I guess you can try simply removing the key from `remember` and do `offset = initOffset` in the next line (although now the name `initOffset` is not ideal because it's not only an initial value anymore).

Comment: @MaciejCiemięga Thanks, but I've tried this already. Doesn't work as expected because `offset` resets to `initOffset` every time the composable function gets called, which is not what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pointerInput` captures all the state variables used inside. With new `initOffset` you're creating a new mutable state, but `pointerInput` keeps updating the old reference.

You need to restart it by passing the same value(s) to `key`:

```
pointerInput(initOffset) { /*...*/ }
```